# Show the latest value using pivot table in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have this table

[image: Table screenshot]

and I want to get the latest -by date- "latest Sum" value of every "From".
I expect something like :

```
2018-02-03 | person1 | 9200
2018-02-05 | person2 | 2600
```

I created a pivot table but apparently I made something wrong. Here it's what I got
[image]

I want it to show only the latest date

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step guide describing one possible way in which to obtain the result that you require:

---

1. I've started with your current setup:

   A table containing the relevant data, and a pivot table created using the default options, with the `From` and `Latest Sum` fields as **Row Labels**, and the `Date` field as a **Value**, with the Value Field Setting set to summarise the `Date` field using the `Max` function:

   [image: Pivot table field setup]

   This configuration yields a pivot table as shown in your question:

   [image: Pivot table start]

---

2. Under the **PivotTable Tools** contextual tab, click on **Design** and then on **Subtotals** and select **Do Not Show Subtotals**:

   [image: No Subtotals]

---

3. Now click on **Grand Totals** and select **Off for Rows and Columns**:

   [image: No Grand Totals]

---

4. Now click on **Report Layout** and select **Show in Tabular Form**:

   [image: Tabular Form]

---

5. Select the filter arrow beside the `Latest Sum` field, then select **Value Filters** and finally **Top 10...**:

   [image: Top 10]

---

6. Configure the Value Filter as follows:

   [image: Value Filter]

---

#### Final Result

[image: Final Result]

Comment: Just a comment that it's the sum that needs the value filter, not the "from". I somehow got it wrong so I hope this comment helps.